# Android : how to update a interface method implemented by a class A and update from Class B?

Tags: android, interface

I've declare an interface named

```
public interface listener {
    public void onError();
}
```

Implemented this interface in a class A.
I've another service B which I open via `startService(new Intent(this, B.class));`

Now desire is, using that interface when I receive any error in class B, can be notify to class A without using Broadcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ActivityA` and `ServiceB` are in the same process, you can use `bindService(Intent intent, ServiceConnection conn, int flags)` instead of `startService` to initiate the service. And the `conn` will be a inner class just like:

```
private ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mMyService = ((ServiceB.MyBinder) service).getService();
        mMyService.setListener(new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onError() {
                // ...
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mMyService = null;
    }
};
```

`mMyService` is the instance of your `ServiceB`.

In `ServiceB`, just override `onBind`:

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new MyBinder();
}
```

and add the following class in `ServiceB`:

```
public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    public ServiceB getService() {
        return ServiceB.this;
    }
}
```

in addition, add a public method:

```
public void setListener(Listener listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
}
```

so you can notify `ActivityA` in `ServiceB` like:

```
someMethod(){
    // ...
    mListener.onError();
}
```

ps: bindService will be like this:

`this.bindService(intent, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

and do not forget

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    this.unbindService(conn);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Euporie, in case of binding service, is onStartCommand() didn't get called?

Comment: @Pankaj bind service will not trigger onStartCommand, it calls onBind